# htaccess two vars to display two folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get my htaccess to rewrite the url to display two folders rather than two vars.

Here is my url:

www.MyWebsite.com/index.php?p=info&id=1234

That is actual url but I want it to display this: 
www.MyWebsite.com/info/1234

Here is the code for the htaccess but it does not work for the second var.

```
DirectoryIndex index_good.html index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tjshow/
# RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/*$ ?p=$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/*$ ?p=$1&id=$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/*$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/*$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/*$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&link=$3 [L]
```

The first one works fine but the second one is giving me a page but with all kinds of internal broken links and images.

This one works:
www.MyWebsite.com/index.php?p=info

And it displays this only, which is what I want it to do:
www.MyWebsite.com/info

But if I add the second var there like this
http://mywebsite.com/tjshow/second
Then the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Using the above rule will leave you with the URL: `www.MyWebsite.com/info/1234`